# Working on dynamic responses from a data source in klipfolio

Tags: klipfolio

Basically, In our data source, I have used facebook graph api to get the list of all posts including likes, shares and comments for each post.
I receive a json response in which we are getting "shares" keys presence is inconsistent which means inside json array which consists facebook post json object that in some cases have shares key value and in some cases its absent.
So, while using this data source in our klip, "shares" key value are not mapped correctly with the other post details.
It is because, when we use data source like this : @/data/shares/count , it will provide the value of shares for each post but in some cases where "shares" key is not present or absent for that data, then it replaces the value by the next found "shares" key value but it needs to be 0 so that data in the klip should be mapped exactly.

DATA SOURCE 
[image]

KLIP
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to Facebook not returning a JSON record if there is no data for that record, you will need to manipulate the data with xpath axes. If you want to "pad" 0 where there is no record, you will also need to use LOOKUP(). For example:

Shares = @/data/shares/count

66 records

IDs where there are shares= @/data/id[preceding-sibling::count]

66 records

```
LOOKUP(@/data/id,
        @/data/id[preceding-sibling::count],
          @/data/shares/count)
```

LOOKUP will return 100 records and pad where there is no share count value.